# python3.x multiprocessing cycling without "if __name__ == '__main__':"

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have this file (it doesn't make any useful work, it's only for learning):

```
import multiprocessing,sys
def parent(numproc=2):
    print ('at start')
    childs=[]
    print ('bfore Pipe')
    (parentEnd,childEnd)=multiprocessing.Pipe()
    i=0
    print ('printing i:',i)
    child=multiprocessing.Process(target=child_proc, args=(childEnd,i))
    print ('created child')
    child.start()
    print ('started child')
    print ('joining child')
    child.join()
    print ('joined child')
    print ('exeted from for i in childs')
    mins=[1,2]
    print ('task ended. result: ',min(mins))
def child_proc(pipe,name):
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent()
```

in this form it runs perfectly:

```
at start
bfore Pipe
printing i: 0
created child
started child
joining child
joined child
exeted from for i in childs
task ended. result:  1
```

but if I put in end of file instead of

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent()
```

only

```
parent()
```

it falls in cycle...

```
at start
bfore Pipe
printing i: 0
created child
started child
joining child
at start
bfore Pipe
printing i: 0
created child
started child
joining child
at start
bfore Pipe
printing i: 0
created child
started child
joining child
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Why?! What different makes this if clause?

Comment: check what the `if __name__` condition mean...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue with `multiprocessing` on MS Windows: the main module is imported by the child tasks, so any code not protected by the `if __name__ . . .` clause gets run again, resulting in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

The subprocess has the following `__name__`: `__parents_main__` and not `__main__` any more. This is why your process does not loop when you are testign the `__name__` variable.

For more information on this have a look to the chapter [Safe importing of main module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#windows)